# Laravel SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am building a simple search function on Laravel, and I get the error:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'landmarks' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from`locations`where exists (select * from`landmarks`where`locations`.`id`=`landmarks`.`location_id`and`landmarks`LIKE %%))`

My search function consist of a textbox in my view and I want to display the results underneath it after clicking on search. However, in my SearchController the following code is found in my index function:

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $landmarks = $request->input('location');
    //if($landmarks != ''){
      $locations = Location::whereHas('landmark', function($query) use ($landmarks) {
          $query->where('landmarks', 'LIKE', '%' . $landmarks . '%');
      })->get();
    //}

    return view('pages.search', compact('location'));
  }
```

I suspect it to be the problem that my 'location' input is empty. I am not sure how to handle this.

Comment: Is landmarks table?

Comment: Yes it is a table - my aim is to be able to enter a Location name in the textbox and then the results of landmarks must come up. The relationships are set.

Comment: you must use column in where, not table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use eager loading `->with()` instead

```
$locations = Location::with(['landmark' => function($query) use ($landmarks) {
     $query->where('_the_column_name_on_your_landmarks_table', 'LIKE', '%'
                   . $landmarks . '%');
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $landmarks = $request->input('location');
    //if($landmarks != ''){
      $locations = Location::whereHas('landmarks', function($query) use ($landmarks) {
          $query->where('landmark', 'LIKE', '%' . $landmarks . '%');
      })->get();
    //}

    return view('pages.search', compact('location'));
  }
```

I assume "landmarks" is your relationships or method name and you have "landmark" as column name.

whereHas method first parameter should be the relationship or method name and then on where method first parameter it should be a column name that exists on the related table landmarks.